# Flat nested object array with one property extracted in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, recursion

Considering i got a such code:

```js
type RouteConfig = {
  path: string;
  text: string;
  routes?: RouteConfig[];
};

const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    text: "home"
  },
  {
    path: "/user",
    text: "user",
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/user/info",
        text: "user info"
      },
      {
        path: "/user/books",
        text: "user books"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const routeEntries = ["/", "/user", "/user/info", "/user/books"]; // ?? how to get it Programmatically instead of hard coding.
```

The `routes` is a tree-like nested object array, each node might contains sub routes node.

The question is simple, how do i get `routeEntries` based on existed routes defined above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function that will gather every path value, like :

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAwnAdgMwJYHMoC8UA3gFBRRgCGwAFgFxQDOwATturgNzlTIAewRi3aceFVomRMA-I3hJUGHLgDaAXR4BfHqQDGGFlEmKm8qUqx4NhKKt5kKFanUYByAPRuANLwoChKDdaOABbCB9eLV8KRycXBiCPBCYIVkinPghBdxS0jKcTaUZ7TNi-MoT3ZNTWDw5MOAKyrJygvNYoBqaYsuiK8pbnGkTPDo8AIzg4AGsmZrKA3NqoKdn53sz+zPVe-s1SUkwEdD1gbAwobLYqM4AFEYAKABMaKnNFNCs1dQBKEl4rAgwAQrHQUFewCoADogc8EHoII9HsBQmBhGwOD9vFB+P8CAA+AGZbCYKAo8AQOBk-iwixMKAAQgIRDcJ2eEBw6Agzzc-zimVRYFspSG0PFQs2ZXF0OurFuwAedEetKKECYvylFAOW0OgrR0LAKVoKsNI1+ukyQJBYL4aPEUGidj+2kOBnQRjVAFF0Jj1bY5QqlSa1RrdO6mHAADYQaFRuC4R7e33sdUWoA)

```
type RouteConfig = {
  path: string;
  text: string;
  routes?: RouteConfig[];
};

const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    text: 'home',
  },
  {
    path: '/user',
    text: 'user',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/user/info',
        text: 'user info',
      },
      {
        path: '/user/books',
        text: 'user books',
      },
    ],
  },
];

function extractPath(data: RouteConfig[]) {
  return data.reduce((tmp: string[], x) => {
    if (typeof x.routes !== 'undefined') {
      tmp = [
        ...tmp,
        ...extractPath(x.routes),
      ];
    }

    tmp.push(x.path);

    return tmp;
  }, []);
}

const routeEntries = extractPath(routes);

console.log(routeEntries);
```